# To use doPost yet stay in the same page

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Hi I am working on a webbased application with JSPs and servlets. I have a page which has a button in it. I have written some javascript to pop-up a small window when the button is clicked and also it invokes the doPost method. The code is something like this --

```
]
"<form name='downloadFrm1' method='post' action='S2VServlet' 
..  ..
"<input name='submitBtn' type='submit'  value='Download Files With Warnings' onClick="+popup+">\n"+

"</form><BR></div><p><BR></p> \n";
```

However, I invoke the doPost method only to do some internal work. I don't want the parent page to be redirected anywhere. But what is happening is that when I click on the button the small popup window appears but the parent page also moves to a blank page. How can I make the parent page stay as is and not get redirected ? The code for doPost is something like ths--

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest p_req, HttpServletResponse p_res) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            String downloadKey = p_req.getParameter(DOWNLOAD_KEY_ELEMENT);
            ....
            if (//put my condition)) {
//just set some internal value and return
                ....
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without ajax (javascript). The standard request/response cycle requires a change in the page.

Take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You can do `$.post("S2VServlet", {param:param})` which will execute in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can end your doPost method doing doGet. Doing so will "repeat" the page, but the user thinks he/she has not moved.

Comment: Sorry, your answer makes technically no sense. Are you sure that you've the basic concepts right?